# Remove all elements from QVector which are smaller than 0

Tags: qt, qvector

I have a `QVector`

```
 QVector(48, 64,  31, -2, 14, 5, 7, -3, -1, 13)
```

I want to know how to use Qt mechanism to remove all the elements that are smaller than 0.
How do I do this in a simple way? 
Thanks

Comment: try using [this method](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

QVector's interface allows it to be used with the std algorithms, so you can just use the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom)

```
QVector<int> vec;
...
vec.erase(std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](int i) { return i < 0; }), 
          vec.end());
```

**By way of explanation:**

`remove_if` takes a range of iterators (`vec.begin(), vec.end()`), and moves all elements for which the provided lambda returns true to the end. It then returns an iterator to the beginning of this range.

`erase` takes a range of iterators (the returned value from `remove_if` and `vec.end()`) and erases them from the vector.

**Working example:**

```
#include <QVector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    QVector<int> vec { 1, 2, 3, -1, -2, -3, 4, 5, 6, -7, -8, -1, 1, 2, 3 };

    // erase all elements less than 0
    vec.erase(std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](int i) { return i < 0; }),
              vec.end());

    // print results
    for (int i : vec)
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

> ```
> ./a.out  
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3
> ```

Comment: Exactly, when profiling both solutions Remi's solution takes about 2x time compared with this solution...

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create your list
QVector<int> listIntegers;
... 

// Remove all numbers < 0 from QVector<int> 
QMutableVectorIterator<int> i(listIntegers);
while (i.hasNext()) {
    if (i.next() < 0)
        i.remove();
}
```

You can also adapt this piece of code to do what you want, just by changing the condition inside the while loop.

Comment: JLev did not suggest using iterators. The question is a typical application of the [Erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) and this is what JLev suggested. I profiled both solutions, this solution takes about 2x the time requisite by the erase-remove idiom. As it might resize the container multiple times during the operation...

Comment: @SteveLorimer, No, it doesn't skip the first element of the array because Qt's Java-style iterators point "in-between" elements rather than at elements themselves, see [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/containers.html#java-style-iterators)